# export/append csv in lots of 1000 powershell

Tags: powershell, crash, export

I'm trying to extract all the .txt and .pdf files from a set location, after a set date, and export them to csv. It works upto a point but when I feed it too much data it crashes (like sorting a server). I assume the memory gets full. It must also recurse as it currently does.  If I simply add `-Append` after `Export-Csv` it tells me that "The appended object does not have a property that corresponds to the following column:" and to add `-Force` but if I add `-Force` after `-Append` it tells me " Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid". I've been looking at the `ForEach` Cmdlet but to no avail. Looking for a bit of wisdom if you've got it :)

```
Param(
$startdate = (read-host -Prompt "Enter date"),
$today     = (Get-Date),      
$RelPath = (read-host -Prompt "Enter filepath"),
$RelFiles = "FullName"
)
 Get-ChildItem -Path $RelPath"*.pdf", "*.txt" -Recurse|
Where-Object  { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $startdate -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt 
$today}|select -Property  $RelFiles |sort -Property $RelFiles |export-csv 
C:\PowershellNewWork\New.csv
```

Comment: *when I feed it too much data it crashes* - with what error message? Yes `|sort` will store everything up in memory, but Windows uses disk space as virtual memory, so unless you have a) manually limited that, or b) run out of disk space, this should merely slow down a lot rather than crash. Also your command with `-Path $RelPath"*.pdf","*.txt` probably isn't doing what you want. It looks like it will search your chosen path for PDFs, and the current path for TXT files. Try `Get-ChildItem -Path $RelPath -Include *.pdf,*.txt -Recurse`

Comment: Cheers for the help :) I would have posted an error msg but it only crashed when my boss ran it on the server. For anyone else in the future this one saves as it goes

Comment: Cheers for the help :) I would have posted an error msg but it only crashed when my boss ran it on the server. For anyone else in the future this one saves as it goes     Param(
     $startdate = (read-host -Prompt "Enter date"),
     $today     = (Get-Date -DisplayHint Date),      
    $RelPath = (read-host -Prompt "Enter filepath"),
   $RelFiles = "FullName"
  )
   Get-ChildItem -Path $RelPath -Include "*.pdf", "*.txt" -Recurse|
   Where-Object  { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $startdate -and 
   $_.LastWriteTime -lt $today}|
      select -Property FullName| export-csv  D:\workexp\New.csv

Comment: Param(
$startdate = (read-host -Prompt "Enter date"),
$today     = (Get-Date -DisplayHint Date),      
$RelPath = (read-host -Prompt "Enter filepath"),
$RelFiles = "FullName"
)
 Get-ChildItem -Path $RelPath -Include "*.pdf", "*.txt" -Recurse|
Where-Object  { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $startdate -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $today}|
 select -Property FullName|
export-csv  D:\workexp\New.csv

Comment: gee that looks ugly tried to fix head sore, thanks again to the community

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need just one column, conserve the memory and make the script faster:

- [IO.DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) is faster than `Get-ChildItem`
- [Collections.Generic.SortedSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx) is faster than `Sort` and doesn't duplicate the contents
- Write the array as a text file instead of Export-Csv. Manually add doublequotes to each value
- Instead of pipelining, use a much faster `foreach` statement and plain `if` checks

```
$files = [Collections.Generic.SortedSet[string]]@()
foreach ($file in ([IO.DirectoryInfo]$RelPath).EnumerateFiles('*', 'AllDirectories') {
    if (($file.Extension -eq '.pdf' -or $file.Extension -eq '.txt') -and
        $file.LastWriteTime -gt $startdate -and $file.LastWriteTime -lt $today)
    {
        $files.Add('"' + $file.$RelFiles + '"') >$null
    }
}
$UTF8noBOM = [Text.UTF8Encoding]$false
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines('r:\out.csv', '"' + $RelFiles + '"', $UTF8noBOM)
[IO.File]::AppendAllLines('r:\out.csv', $files, $UTF8noBOM)
```

Tested in PowerShell 5 on a highly nested folder with 96K files that produces a CSV with 2500 rows:
2 seconds vs 15 seconds for the original code,
3 MB vs 20 MB memory used.

Comment: Don't have a PSv5 to test right now, but at least on the older versions `[void]$files.Add('"' + $file.$RelFiles + '"')` would be even faster (by a very slim margin) ;)

Comment: @whatever, `[void]` has exactly the same speed as `>$null` as measured in the setup mentioned in my answer. Don't be a "hax0r".

Comment: `[void]` is noticeably faster only in a non-practical synthetic test like `foreach ($i in 1..1e6) { [void]$i }` where there is no useful code. In real world code the time needed to run a useful function exceeds type-casting or null-redirection time by *orders of magnitude*.

Comment: From a very quick measurement it's twice as fast doing exactly what you are doing. Will it be a noticeable difference? Most likely not. Might it make sense to get used to always using the most efficient way (especially if it has no downsides)? Possibly. Not trying to be "hax", personally I always like to pick up little things like that.

Comment: @whatever, evidently you don't know how to perform reliable benchmarking. If it's about the code in the answer, the first run is always much slower as it involves reading from the physical medium.

Comment: Wow Cheers guys that's much flasher than what I've been writing, However got the error msg now and its because I haven't converted $Startdate do a Datetime object. so it can't compare all dates, It just acted like it was for dates with a day value less than 10.  I'm looking at [datetime] ::parse atm and will hopefully crack it.

Answer (score 0):

Great community, Here's the final code to fix the problem

```
Param(
$startdate = (read-host -Prompt "Enter date"),
$startdate2 =[datetime]::ParseExact("$startdate", "dd/MM/yy", $null),
$today     = (Get-Date),      
$RelPath = (read-host -Prompt "Enter filepath"),
$RelFiles = "FullName"
)
 Get-ChildItem -Path $RelPath"*.pdf", "*.txt" -Recurse|
Where-Object  { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $startdate2 -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $today}|
select -Property  $RelFiles |export-csv C:\PowershellNewWork\New.csv
```